# How to fix Firebase 9.0 invalid API key

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have my API key stored in a local .env file in my React project, and it is correctly pasted directly from my firebase console setup page. However, I receive this error:

```
Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
createErrorInternal
D:/src/core/util/assert.ts:101

   98 |   );
   99 | }
  100 | 
> 101 | return _DEFAULT_AUTH_ERROR_FACTORY.create(
      | ^  102 |   authOrCode,
  103 |   ...(rest as AuthErrorListParams<K>)
  104 | );
```

I don't see why React is giving me an error.
I initialized Firebase in the following file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();

export default app;
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(firebaseConfig)` and checked if all env variables are correct?

Comment: I am not sure if its required field, but you are missing measurementID param... Maybe it is required in your case? Just wondering...
Or another thing can be that you are trying to run it on localhost. Env variables does not work on localhost.

Comment: Also check whether the file naming is correct. line `.env.local`, begins with a `.`

Comment: `npm i` might help as well. I had to run it twice.

Comment: For those that tried all of the above, console.log the key and it all seemed ok...what worked for me was : apiKey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY}` instead of: apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY.

Answer (score 5):

It seems your `env` variables are invalid.

You can check a few things though.

1. You have to restart your server if your server is already running and you are changing/adding the `env` variables.
2. Make sure your `env` variable names are correct.
3. Make sure your `env` file is in root folder means it should be with your your `src` and `public` folder.

Comment: restart the server before you try it out, this worked for me . thanks

Answer (score 3):

this problem occurs because , you might have written your env file in wrong way like this

```
// Wrong: 
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY=”AHEHEHR”

// Right:
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY=AHEHEHR
```

you don't have use any trailing  comma or quotes , after or around you api key ,and after making changes to your env file you have to restart server

Comment: i dont think the "" make any difference

Comment: well, strangely enough, that resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

You can restart yours react app by clicking npm start in CMD. The same things happened to me after setting the environment variable. Hopefully, that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are corectly given the name of .env.local file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).